# Get all users in SharePoint?

Tags: user-profile, spgridview

If my companies AD is the SharePoint user base, how would I get all the employee's First/Last Name and Extension in C#?

I plan on displaying them with SPGridView.

Comment: Why a grid? Why not use a search query and provide a alphabetical catalog of users by first or last name? The performance will be WAY better and it can be done client side.

Answer (score 1):

There is no client side code to iterate through user profiles. You can do through server side, [Reference Here](http://anthony-verschraegen.blogspot.jp/2014/12/sharepoint-c-loop-through-user-profiles.html)

If you have no choice other than client side, there is a workaround.
Note:

1. Your User profile data is perfectly managed.
2. All users have the proper hierarchy.

Now start with company Top level employee and get all his/her direct reports

```
_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='" + encodeURIComponent(accountName) + "'&$select=DirectReports"
```

After getting all direct reportees to top level/CEO , iterate through these users and try to get their direct reportees, continue looping till you get last or zero direct reportees. This way you will get all employee.

Note:

1. This will skip the user profiles which does not have any manager assigned to them.
2. Depending on your size of organization it can take too long to run.